# ASP.NET Binding linq query results to HTML.DropDownList() using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to build a drop down list with a single database call.

My table consists of an Id column and a CompanyName column.  I need to display the CompanyName to the user and when one is selected set the Id for the page to Id.

I have put a simple model together to store the information:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Portal.Models
{
    public class CompanyListId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyListIdDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CompanyListId> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I am having an issue with the controller and razor call in the view.

My controller:

```
public void CompanyListIdSearch()
        {
            using (var dc = new CompanyListIdDBContext())
            {
                var content = from p in db.Companies
                                select new { p.CoId, p.CompanyName };
            }
        }
```

Razor call in View:

```
<div id="partners" class="linen">

                        @{Html.DropDownList("CompanyListIdSearch", new SelectList(Model.CompanyName));}
                    </div>
```

Grabbing the model at the top of a view `@model Portal.Models.CompanyListId`

So at a high level what I am trying to do is have a view that calls the controller with a razor tag, the controller updates the model with data and then that data is displayed in the drop down.  Am I approaching this the wrong way?

I am getting this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Portal.Models.DashboardContents', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Portal.Models.CompanyListId'.
```

Comment: Viewbag works. Using ViewModels is another option. [View Models](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. You can't call a method in `DropDownList` like that.

Firstly, put that collection of items in your `ViewBag`:

```
using (var dc = new CompanyListIdDBContext())
{
    var content = from p in db.Companies
       select new { p.CoId, p.CompanyName };

    ViewBag.CompaniesList = content
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.CompanyName,
            Value = c.CoId.ToString()
        }).ToList();
}
```

Make sure you call that function in your action result before returning the view.

Lastly, just use your model property and switch to `DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, ViewBag.CompaniesList);
```

---

**A better approach however**, is to not use the `ViewBag` and to use a view model instead. Something like this:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CompaniesList { get; set; }
}
```

Then your action method would be something like:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    var model = new CompanyViewModel();

    using (var dc = new CompanyListIdDBContext())
    {
        var content = from p in db.Companies
            select new { p.CoId, p.CompanyName };

        model.CompaniesList = content
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = c.CompanyName,
                Value = c.CoId.ToString()
            }).ToList();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Then your view would use the new model:

```
@model CompanyViewModel
```

Then your dropdown would be:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, Model.CompaniesList)
```

Comment: Is a ViewModel fundamentally different from a regular Model? Could I reuse what I have above?  Or is the function of the ViewModel to allow me to push model data to a separate object specifically for views?

Comment: @ZachM. It's basically a representation of your Model created for display/edit purposes. It means you don't have to expose your model classes to the view too (especially if they are used as EF/ORM classes).

Comment: One of the issues i'm running into is that coid is an integer and select list items does not like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am having trouble implementing what you suggested. I think it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: @ZachM. Ah of course, then all that needs to change is the `Select` into the `SelectListItem`, change it to `Value = c.CoId.ToString()`, MVC will automatically convert it back to an `int` when the Model is posted :)

Comment: @ZachM. If you check my edit, I've updated both sets of code to do what I just suggested.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm still getting the `.ToString()` error, was there some where else you are saying to change select?
`.Select(c => new SelectListItem` is what I am using.  Oh and thank you for the help this has been very insightful.

Comment: @ZachM Yeah, you see that `Value = c.CompanyId` at the end? Change it to `Value = c.CompanyId.ToString()`

Comment: Now that I am looking at what you posted, how does the model in the view know what Id should be? i'm not setting that value anywhere in the above.

Comment: @Zach Ah I was under the impression you weren't loading anything. You could change it so that the action method took an `id`, then retrieved that company by `id`, then set the `model.CompanyId` and `model.CompanyName` to be those of that company