# Storing linq query results in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am attempting to Query a database and store those results in a model, one of the columns is numerical and one is string data:

Model:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Portal.Models
{
    public class CompanyListId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyListIdDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CompanyListId> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult SelectCompanyFromDropdown()
            {
                using (var dc = new CompanyListIdDbContext())
                {
                    var content = from p in db.Companies
                                    select new { p.CoId, p.CompanyName };
                }
//I want to set Models ID = to each instance of coid
            //Set Models CompanyName to each instance of companyname

                return PartialView();

            }
```

I am not sure where to go from here, I am attempting to make a drop down from this model.

I updated my code block to:

```
public PartialViewResult SelectCompanyFromDropdown()
        {
            using (var dc = new CompanyListIdDbContext())
            {
                var content = from p in db.Companies
                    select new CompanyListId
                    {
                        Id = p.CoId,
                        CompanyName = p.CompanyName
                    };
                return PartialView(content.ToList());//giving an error
            }
        }
```

And my view to:

```
@model Portal.Models.CompanyListId

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyName, Model.CompanyName)
```

This also doesn't seem to work, I need to return my Model from the action I would think, that way the view can properly use the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Binding linq query results to HTML.DropDownList() using MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140812/asp-net-binding-linq-query-results-to-html-dropdownlist-using-mvc) asked by OP

Comment: No since I have decided to rephrase my question, old questions shouldn't be completely overhauled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should **project** the result to your class `CompanyListId`

```
var content = from p in db.Companies
              select new CompanyListId
                  { 
                    Id = p.CoId, 
                    CompanyName  = p.CompanyName 
                  };
```

EDIT:

I am not sure about the error, but you can try :

```
public PartialViewResult SelectCompanyFromDropdown()
{
    List<CompanyListId> content = null;
    using (var dc = new CompanyListIdDbContext())
    {
        content = (from p in db.Companies
            select new CompanyListId
            {
                Id = p.CoId,
                CompanyName = p.CompanyName
            }).ToList();
    }
    return PartialView(content);
}
```

Comment: Like your answer.  Typing race!

Comment: So in this instance my `var content` will be an object of CompanyListId and if i wanted to return this model to my view would I just `return PartialView(content)` ?

Comment: It will be `IEnumerable<CompanyListId>`, you can convert it to a `List<CompanyListId>` using `.ToList()` at the end, or if you want to select a single object then use `.First()` at the end.

Comment: Updated my question above.

Comment: @ZachM., not really sure about the error but I just updated the answer, You can try that.

Comment: Arguement type List<CompanyListId> is not assignable to model.companylistid.

Answer (score 3):

You can just select a new instance of your class like so:

```
var content = from p in db.Companies
              select new CompanyListId 
              { 
                  Id = p.CoId, 
                  CompanyName = p.CompanyName 
              };
```